# Is it necessary for a AsyncTask to be an inner class?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I heard that an AsyncTask is not quite useful in the sense that the activity that is the parent of AsyncTask cannot be destroyed to free the memory in case of changing of the orientation of the mobile phone until the AsyncTask completes its functions(as it is an inner class and it contains references of the parent class). So what if we do not declare the AsyncTask as an inner class and define it as an independent class all together....will this memory leak issue be resolved then?

Comment: "will this memory leak issue be resolved then?" -- probably not. There are ways to avoid memory leaks with `AsyncTask`, but they tend to be complicated, such as using a retained fragment to manage the `AsyncTask`. Conversely, there are *many* ways to screw it up. This is why Google officially deprecated `AsyncTask` last year, as a strong signal that you should be considering alternatives: RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, `LiveData`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want nested class, always create a **static** nested class that extends AsyncTask. Because instance of a static nested class does not keep reference to its enclosing class. You can use WeakReference to keep reference of enclosing members (if necessary).

> So what if we do not declare the AsyncTask as an inner class and
> define it as an independent class all together....will this memory
> leak issue be resolved then?

It depends, if you keep strong reference to some Activity/Fragment/UI classes, leak may occur. Using singleton pattern might help cope with memory leaks.